# Tab, Caps lock, Tilde/backtick, Escape keys stopped working on Apple Wired Keyboard after macOS 10.14.6 update

Tags: macos, keyboard, mojave, software-update, karabiner

I am using Mid 2015 15" MBP with Thunderbolt display and Apple Wired Keyboard. Recently after an update to macOS Mojave 10.14.6 certain keys on my Apple Wired Keyboard stopped working. Keys are:
1. Escape
2. Tilde / Back tick
3. Tab
4. Caps lock
I have confirmed the same using Keyboard Event Viewer
[image]

I have tried the following:
1. SMC reset using Cmd+ Opt + P + R
2. Rebooting the system
3. Adding a USB extension between mac and Apple keyboard
4. Tried on different USB ports

Any suggestion on what could be causing this?

Comment: And the same keys work on the MBP's own keyboard? Any chance of testing the keyboard on another Mac?